# Forming logic gates from boolean expression

Tags: logic

I'm assigned to draw a logic gate for the expression f(x,y,z) = x+y'z, but I'm just learning all about logic gates and all the theorems right now so I'm totally confused. Which functions should I use to represent each part? Would y'z be a NAND gate? Can you have a gate coming out of a gate in order to combine these?

Comment: Write out a truth table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "'" sign represents the complement of the variable (or a NOT), while the '+' sign represents an OR. y'z would be an AND between the negation of y and z. And yes, you can have the output of a gate wired to an input of another. Considering the precedences you should first negate y, then do an AND between negated y (which is y') and z, and finally do an OR between the output of the previous AND and x

Comment: Ok I was trying to find an AND gate where one input was negated and the other was not. Thanks so much!